# Могу ли я использовать IdentityServer4 spa JS UI вместо ASP .NET core MVC?

Tags: angular2, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Я посмотрел пример IdentityServer4 UI ([IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/tree/release)) UI в нем на основе ASP .NET core MVC. Примеры spa JS UI я не нашел. Безопасно ли использовать spa js UI, и как это сделать?